# How to do an ajax call as a result for a previous ajax call which in return should dispatch multiple actions

Tags: rxjs6

I'm trying to implement a scenario in rxjs where:

1. I make an ajax call to an api to fetch some data.
2. If the jwt token has expired, I get a response with the updated
   token
3. If token has been updated, I need to re-execute the previous API
   call
4. If not I return the result as usual.

To do that, I'm trying to execute a promise in map() when the token has been updated, to re-execute the initial API call

Everytime it says:  "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions" –

```
const fetchEpic = (action$, store) =>
    action$.pipe(filter(filterActions)).pipe(
        mergeMap((actionParams) => {

                const ajaxObservables = ajax(request).pipe(
                        takeUntil(action$.ofType(`${type}_CANCEL`, CANCEL_ALL_FETCH)),
                        map( ({ response: payload}) => {
                            if (payload.tokenUpdated) {

                                const promiseFetch = () => new Promise(resolve => {
                                    ajax(request).pipe(map(({ response }) => resolve(response)));
                                });


                                return from(promiseFetch).pipe(
                                    concatMap((result) => of(
                                        { type: SET_USER_TOKENS, payload },
                                        {...onCompleteAction, payload: result, extraParameters}
                                    )),
                                    catchError(err => {
                                        console.log(err)
                                    })
                                );

                            }
                            else if (isJWTError(payload)) {
                                return ({ type: USER_LOGOUT })
                            } else {
                                return ({...onCompleteAction, payload, extraParameters});
                            }
                        }),
                        catchError(({ xhr: { response: payload }}) => {
                            const obsLogoutAction = (of({ type: USER_LOGOUT, error: true}));
                            const obsReturnAction = (of({ type, payload, error: true}));
                            if (isJWTError(payload)) {
                                return obsLogoutAction;
                            }
                            return obsReturnAction
                        })
                    );
                let obs = [...loadingActionObservable, ajaxObservables ];

                return concat(...obs);
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by using combination of flatMap and concat.

The following repeats API calls when token has been updated and dispatch 2 actions:

```
ajax(request).pipe(flatMap(({ response }) => {
                                    console.log('response', response);
                                    return concat(
                                        of({ type: SET_USER_TOKENS, payload }),
                                       of({...onCompleteAction, payload: response, extraParameters})
                                    );
                                }));
```

The whole observable:

```
const ajaxObservables = ajax(request).pipe(
                        takeUntil(action$.ofType(`${type}_CANCEL`, CANCEL_ALL_FETCH)),
                        //map(({ response: payload }) => payload),
                        map(({ response: payload }) => {

                            console.log(payload);
                            if (payload.tokenUpdated) {
                                options.headers['x-xsrf-token'] = payload.csrfToken;
                               // first dispatch action to update user token
                                return ajax(request).pipe(flatMap(({ response }) => {
                                    console.log('response', response);
                                    return concat(
                                        of({ type: SET_USER_TOKENS, payload }),
                                       of({...onCompleteAction, payload: response, extraParameters})
                                    );
                                }));
                                    //return { type: SET_USER_TOKENS, payload };
                                // re-execute ajax request
                            }
                             else if (isJWTError(payload)) {
                                return of({ type: USER_LOGOUT })
                            } else {
                                return of({...onCompleteAction, payload, extraParameters});
                            }
                        }),
                        flatMap((res) => {
                            console.log(res);
                          return res;
                        }),
                        //repeatWhen(action$.ofType(SET_USER_TOKENS, SET_USER_TOKENS)),
                        catchError((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                            const { xhr: { response: payload } = {} } = error;
                            const obsLogoutAction = (of({ type: USER_LOGOUT, error: true}));
                            const obsReturnAction = (of({ type, payload, error: true}));
                            if (payload && isJWTError(payload)) {
                                return obsLogoutAction;
                            }
                            return obsReturnAction
                        })
                    );
```